# How to make mutiple subscriptions one after another in angular 4?

Tags: angular, observable

How can I do multiple subscriptions and do a common operation after getting data in angular?

```
myfunction() {

    this.service1.function1.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("get this first");

        this.service2.function2.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("get this second");

            this.service3.function3.subscribe((data) => {
                console.log("get this third");
            }

    if(first && second && third){
        dosomeoperations;
    }
```

I know it's wrong to do like above. How to do this in a proper way in angular  I'm new to angular. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` operator

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';

    const combined = combineLatest(
      this.service1.function1, 
      this.service2.function2, 
      this.service3.function3);

        const subscribe = combined.subscribe(
          ([fn1, fn2, fn3]) => {

            console.log(
            `Fn1: ${fn1},
             Fn2: ${fn2},
             Fn3: ${fn3}`
            );
          }
        );
```

Comment: you can pass a second function to subscribe(FIRST_FUNCTION, (error) => console.log(error))

Comment: if you want to catch errors for each. you can use this.service1.function1.catch((error) => console.log(error))

Comment: Can you give some example?